# Is it possible to map the RMB when in "Command Mode" of Mass Effect 1?

Tags: mass-effect

Okay, a bit of explanation:

The "Command Mode" in *Mass Effect 1* is my term for that HUD brought up when one presses the spacebar during combat. It's where you can order your squadmates to do action and/or deploy their powers.

The RMB is used in the "Command Mode" to shift the view around, and also to point one's squadmates on which opponents they should target when they cast their magic.

Now, in *Mass Effect 2*, I can map the RMB to the "B" key (or any keyboard key), no matter the mode. However, try as I might (Google searches, and outright experimentation) I can't seem to find how -- in *ME1* -- I can map the RMB to the "B" key.

**Note:** I ***can*** -- and already have -- map the Zoom key (RMB outside of Command Mode) to "B", but I can't map the RMB inside Command Mode to "B".

I need to do this for two reasons:

1. My mouse's RMB seems to be dying, and
2. I'm using a [**Wolf King Warrior** gaming keyboard](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823146002), and the "B" key is oh-so-conveniently located near my thumb.

I'd appreciate any guidance to solving this issue.

Comment: You could write a autohotkey script to press right mouse when you press a key

Comment: @kalina that would map the RMB _everywhere_, though; I only need to map it when in "Command Mode" ... but then again, the RMB was indeed dying so your suggestion makes sense. HOWEVER... I've purchased a new mouse instead, so I am no longer in dire need to do the mapping. Thanks for commenting!